# How to conditionally render a component from the property of a constant in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to conditionally render a component based on the header property of my constant.
Basically if the header is  Woffy --> Render Component1
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Component1 from '../Collection/Component1';
import Component2 from '../Collection/Component2';

const pets = [
  {
    header: 'Woffy',
    image: '/img/dog.png'
  },
  {
    header: 'kitty',
    image: '/img/cat.png'
  },

class demo class extends React.Component{
render(){
return(
<div>
{header === "Woofy" && <Component1 />}
{header === "kitty" && <Component2 />}
</div>
)
}
}
```

Comment: With which index element of array pets you want to compare the header ?

Comment: Well I have a react dropdown component <Dropdown/> from Fluent UI, I want to display the component based in the dropdown selection, wich I want to asign from the header property. is thar possible ? This is my dropdown <Dropdown
              items={pets}
              placeholder="Zoo world"
            />

Comment: Yes you can achieve this, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well I have a react dropdown component `<Dropdown/>` from Fluent UI, I want to display the component based in the dropdown selection, wich I want to asign from the header property. is that possible ? This is my dropdown `<Dropdown items={pets} placeholder="Zoo world" />`

You can use variable which you are as `value` of the state of Dropdown and then compare the variable to render the component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
const pets = [
    {
      key: "1",
      header: "Woffy",
      image: "/img/dog.png"
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      header: "kitty",
      image: "/img/cat.png"
    }
  ];

const DropdownExample = () => {
  const [dropdownValue, setDropdownValue] = React.useState("3");
  console.log(dropdownValue);
  return (
    <Dropdown
      items={pets}
      value={dropdownValue}
      onChange={(_, data) => setDropdownValue(data.value.header)}
    />
  );
};
```

Now compare this `dropdownValue` variable to render component.

```
<div>
{dropdownValue === "Woofy" && <Component1 />}
{dropdownValue === "kitty" && <Component2 />}
</div>
```

Comment: This solves the question, I just added export default DropdownExample; to can export my component to the render page. With your help I have learned that class components in React does not support Hooks BUT I can mix class and function components :) You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `header` value by using `Array.map` method and then return the desired output.

```
<div>
  {pets.map((e) => {
    if (e.header === "Woffy") {
      return <Component1 />;
    } else if (e.header === "kitty") {
      return <Component2 />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })}
</div>;
```